# iTunes and iPod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-touch

I am new to iPod and iTunes.

I want to know a few, some basic things. I am a Linux guy and iTunes, particularly on Windows feels quite alien.

- There are already a lot of apps already on my iTouch which don't open, because it was synced to a different iTunes user earlier. I want all of those apps to be there and add a few more of my own, preferably in bulk. In a single check out. How to do it.
- It has an old firmware. I am ok to pay and upgrade to the latest version of the firmware. But there seem to be better free ways to do that. I googled a bit, about it written in some shady places with not many comments. I seem to trust you guys enough not to be bothered to google more.
- How to sync selected songs, videos and a list of rss feeds of podcasts. Its a pain to include all stuff in iTunes first and then select individually.
- If I upgrade the firmware after syncing stuff, will all the content be available or; is it necessary to upgrade first.
- iPod and iTouch have great UIs, as everyone accepts. But seems like I need a short guide/intro to iTunes. Can you summarize.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please Note - I have typed up a long and complex answer to this question, however in short this is one of the few times I highly recommend you read the manual available [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_touch_3.0_User_Guide.pdf). To answer each one of these in detail will be the same as rewriting the User Manual. All of the references I have quoted in this answer is from there.*

**Applications from the App Store**

> iTunes automatically syncs applications you’ve downloaded or purchased on
> iPod touch to your iTunes library when you connect iPod touch to your computer. This
> lets you access the downloads on your computer and provides a backup if you delete
> applications from iPod touch.

You will need to download these apps again, as they are not linked to your iTunes account. If they had been purchased by the previous owner you will need to purchase them.

**Step to update Firmware**

This is done through iTunes. On the iTouch summary screen in iTunes is an update firmware button which will do everything automatically.
Thanks to [Nagul](https://superuser.com/users/4358/nagul), the iPod Touch firmware is charged for and available from Apple [here](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/softwareupdate.html).
*As per the OP, if the iPod Touch is reset the update is free*

**Syncing Music, Videos and Podcasts**

> **Set up iPod touch for manually managing content:**
> 1 Connect iPod touch to your computer.
> 2 In iTunes, select iPod touch in the sidebar.
> 3 Click the Summary tab and select “Manually manage music and videos.”
> 4 Click Apply.

To reset the phone:

> **Reset all settings:**
>
> Choose General > Reset and tap Reset All Settings.
> All your preferences and settings are reset. Information, such as your contacts and
> calendars, and media, such as your songs and videos, aren’t deleted.
>
> **Erase all content and settings:**
> Connect iPod touch to your computer or a power adapter.
> Choose General > Reset and tap “Erase All Content and Settings.”
> This feature resets all settings to their defaults and removes all your information and
> media on your iPod touch by overwriting the data stored on iPod touch.

For a lot of good tips on using iTunes to manage your iPod, iLounge has some very good tutorial available [here](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/help/)

Comment: In the case of having to re download all apps, how do I reset and format all data, on iPod, first. Thanks!

Comment: The 3.0 firmware is not free for the iPod Touch either: http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/softwareupdate.html

Comment: @nagul As I just found, if you reset it, it is free!

Comment: Now it's time for you to accept this answer - as well as any others for questions you didn't accept answers for.